# How do I run FASM 1.71.17 in Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu

Hello,I am a novice at using Linux i am using Xubuntu off of a flash drive 
and I am wondering how do i run the FASM executable I have already opened the properties dialog and went underneath the permissions tab and selected the option that said "allow this file to run as an executable". I have tried double clicking on it, it did not open the process did not show up on task manager. I am wondering is this a console application.

[Here is the fasm website](http://flatassembler.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation on the website you linked to, you will find that it is a command line program.

> All the versions are designed to be used from the system command line

So you need to open a terminal, find the program, and run it:

```
./program_name
```

If there is any problem preventing it from running it should tell you.

Also, you should go through the documentation to learn how to run the program.

> To execute flat assembler from the command line you need to provide two parameters - first should be name of source file, second should be name of destination file. If no second parameter is given, the name for output file will be guessed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [documentation](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php) and looking at the [examples](http://flatassembler.net/examples.php), if you still have trouble you can find support for FASM [here](http://board.flatassembler.net/)